# Trouble with accuracy at arbitrary points

Tags: linux, lua, fibonacci

```
target="/home/walia6/Math/fib"
os.execute("echo 1 > "..target)
os.execute("echo 1 >> "..target)
while true do
    local handle = io.popen("wc -l < "..target)
    ct = handle:read("*a")
    handle:close()
    os.execute("echo "..ct)

    tmp=("sed -n "..(ct-1).."p "..target)
    --os.execute("echo '"..tmp.."'")
    local handle = io.popen(tmp)
    pn = handle:read("*a")
    handle:close()

    tmp=("sed -n "..(ct-0).."p "..target)
    --os.execute("echo '"..tmp.."'")
    local handle = io.popen(tmp)
    cn = handle:read("*a")
    handle:close()

    os.execute("echo "..(string.format("%.0f",cn+pn)).." >>"..target)
end
```

Above is some code I made while experimenting with Lua in Linux. I was more testing Linux than I was testing Lua.

I noticed, though, that my Fibonacci generator became inaccurate after the 78th number generated. This seems to be a fairly arbitrary number so I cannot think of why it would be erroring like other than some sort of overflow.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most probably an overflow because Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially.

Before Lua 5.3, all numbers in Lua are double-precision floating point numbers. This means that integers up to 52 bits can be represented exactly. Indeed, F(78) = 8944394323791464 can be represented exactly but F(79) = 14472334024676221 cannot.

In Lua 5.3, which has 64-bit integers, Fibonacci numbers up to F(92) = 754011380474634642 can be represented exactly.